# Rails set factory field with an association attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have this model with a self-reference association:

```
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity
  has_many :suboptions, class_name: "Option"
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Option", optional: true
end
```

And I want to create a suboption factory(using FactoryGirl) where the `activity_id` is equal to the parent `activity_id`. How can I do that??

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `after(:build)` and `after(:create)` callbacks as below.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :option do
    transient do
      parent_option nil
      no_of_suboptions nil
    end

    name Faker::Internet.name
    after(:build) do |option, evaluator|
      #option.activity_id = evaluator.activity.id
      if not evaluator.parent_option.blank?
        #option.parent_id = evaluator.parent_option.id
        option.parent = evaluator.parent_option
      end
    end

    factory :option_with_suboptions do
      after(:create) do |option, evaluator|
        create_list(:option, evaluator.no_of_suboptions, :activity => option.activity, :parent => option)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Usage**

`FactoryGirl.create(:option_with_suboptions, :activity => activity, :no_of_suboptions => 5)`

One needs to make sure `activity` object exists. One can set number of `suboptions` to be created using `no_of_suboptions`

**Gemfile**

Add `faker` gem to your Gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'faker'
end
```

Comment: what is this `name Faker::Internet.name` ?

Comment: Sorry. `Faker::Internet.name` generates fake data for you. You can add gem `faker` to your Gemfile and run `bundle`.